# Adding a column based on other 2 columns and by comparing values within the group

Tags: r

I have to fill the column of Cross Affiliation based on the columns Address and Political Party. The logic is that for the same address, if there are multiple persons living there and any of them has different political party than any other person in that address, then cross affiliation for all persons in this address should be "y", otherwise "n".

```
Name    Address                Political party  Cross Affiliation 
Jane    10  W STATE ST  ALBION      D                n
David   10  W STATE ST  ALBION      D                n
Kate    105 W STATE ST  ALBION      R                n
Tom     40  DEER ST  ALBION         D                y
Lee     40  DEER ST  ALBION         D                y
Ann     40  DEER ST  ALBION         R                y
```

I am drawing a blank of how to proceed. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in base R with `ave`:

```
df$cross <- ave(df$Political_party, df$Address, FUN=function(i) length(unique(i)) > 1)
```

This will add a logical vector to your data.frame where it is TRUE if there is more than one party represented in a household. I'd recommend working with logical vectors rather than letters as R will treat these naturally. This returns

```
 df
   Name Address Political_party cross
1  Jane      10               D FALSE
2 David      10               D FALSE
3  Kate     105               R FALSE
4   Tom      40               D  TRUE
5   Lee      40               D  TRUE
6   Ann      40               R  TRUE
```

I had to make minor alterations to your data to read it in, which do not harm the integrity of the result.

**data**

```
df <-
structure(list(Name = c("Jane", "David", "Kate", "Tom", "Lee", 
"Ann"), Address = c(10L, 10L, 105L, 40L, 40L, 40L), Political_party = c("D", 
"D", "R", "D", "D", "R")), .Names = c("Name", "Address", "Political_party"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

This code will work for more than 2 parties. Consider the following data.frame, for example.

```
set.seed(1234)
df2 <- rbind(df, within(df, {Political_party <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], nrow(df), replace=TRUE)
                             Address <- Address + 1L}))
```

Here, I've doubled the number of households and added more parties. The new data.frame is as below.

```
df2
    Name Address Political_party
1   Jane      10               D
2  David      10               D
3   Kate     105               R
4    Tom      40               D
5    Lee      40               D
6    Ann      40               R
7   Jane      11               A
8  David      11               B
9   Kate     106               B
10   Tom      41               B
11   Lee      41               C
12   Ann      41               B
```

Now using the code,

```
df2$cross <- ave(df2$Political_party, df2$Address, FUN=function(i) length(unique(i)) > 1)
```

we get

```
df2
    Name Address Political_party cross
1   Jane      10               D FALSE
2  David      10               D FALSE
3   Kate     105               R FALSE
4    Tom      40               D  TRUE
5    Lee      40               D  TRUE
6    Ann      40               R  TRUE
7   Jane      11               A  TRUE
8  David      11               B  TRUE
9   Kate     106               B FALSE
10   Tom      41               B  TRUE
11   Lee      41               C  TRUE
12   Ann      41               B  TRUE
```

Note that in the new observations, only the singleton household has no cross party. Also note that the values in the previous data.frame are not affected.

Comment: Thanks. I used the code but it didn't work. it produced a result as AC 0, AD 0, AE 0, D 8907, and so on. AC, AD, AE are other levels under Political_Party, and there are about 30 different levels whereas R and D are the largest two levels. I wonder it is because there are more than 2 levels in Political Party variable?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You're question requests a binary variable and you are reporting integer values in the comment. If these are counts of households with cross-party affiliations, then it is possible that none exist in your data.

Comment: sorry that i made it confusing. I think your comment explained why it didn't work. The political_party is not a binary variable, instead it has 30 different levels. Can you please advice how to change the syntax? Thanks.

Comment: The code will work for more than 2 political parties. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. By reading the syntax, I also think it should work on the entire data set. But it still didn't work. I received this warnings msg: 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = FALSE) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated. Any advise?

Comment: Most likely, your Political party variable is a factor. You could convert it to character with `df$Political_party <- as.character(df$Political_party)`. Alternatively, you could do this as a temporary conversion in `ave`: `df2$cross <- ave(as.character(df2$Political_party), df2$Address, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks! this worked. I thought it has to be a factor variable.

Comment: The main uses of factor variables are for statistical modelling and plotting. For most other applications, character variables are preferred as they are easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(Address) %>%
    mutate(Cross_Affiliation = ifelse(n_distinct(Political_party)==1,'n','y'))
df
#Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
#Groups: Address [3]
#   Name                Address Political_party Cross_Affiliation
#   <chr>                  <chr>           <chr>             <chr>
#1  Jane 10  W STATE ST  ALBION               D                 n
#2 David 10  W STATE ST  ALBION               D                 n
#3  Kate 105 W STATE ST  ALBION               R                 n
#4   Tom    40  DEER ST  ALBION               D                 y
#5   Lee    40  DEER ST  ALBION               D                 y
#6   Ann    40  DEER ST  ALBION               R                 y
```